# Can we charge a 12S LiPO battery through a DC safety switch?

Tags: batteries, dc, safety, circuit-protection, lipo

I'm working on a robot that uses a 12S battery as its main power source. The problem is that wanted to add a short circuit protection and an overcurrent protection, so added a DC automatic safety switch that can handle up to 100A of current.

Usually instead of the iChargerX12, that will be "LOAD" (since no power will be applied to the iCharger input), so current is flowing from the switch input to the output (basically from battery to load). But when we apply the iChargerX12 to the Switch's terminals, the current flows the OPPOSITE. From the switch output, to the switch input. Or from the charger T0 the battery. Is this possible?

**When charging, DC SWITCH 1 is OFF to disconnect the load. And the current flows like: iChargerX12 --> BMS --> DC SWITCH 2 (here is the problem) --> Battery. See the image below.**

Note the balance lead is connected to the BMS and only the +/- leads are connected to the charger. This is because the BMS can balance the battery while charging.

[image: The main circuit]Can the LiP0 be charged through the DC switch? Check the switch in the image added. Current wil be flowing from the OUTPUT to the INPUT, reverse of what would usually be the case...

Comment: Isn't it less complicated to have the BMS located nearest the battery?

Comment: @Andyaka so you mean we should remove switch 2 and have the battery connected directly to the BMS? I was worried the BMS may consume power as well and if the battery ever goes below 3.7V/cell that may over-discharge it and let the magic smoke out (well really slow, since the BMS shouldn't consume more than a couple milliamps